# Best way to add items with properties to my nutritional iOS app (Swift 4)?

Tags: swift3

I am developing a nutritional app that shows restaurants > food items > nutritional values for these food items. I want to display them in a table view structure. I was thinking of using a database with an API but I am in a time crunch and I am a beginner and figuring out how to use the USDA database which is completely alien to me, so I am going to manually input 200+ food items into the app. What is the best way to do this and how do I do it? I was trying to do a plist dictionary with restaurants (dictionary) > foods(dictionary)> nutritional values (dictionary) but I am not sure if so many dictionaries is the best/ easiest way to do it. I also thought about creating a separate class and creating an instance of the class with each property (name, restaurant, calories) etc but I am a bit lost on how to do that as well

anything helps thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try making a dashboard application where you can enter the details of the food items that you want to display. For instance, make an app with all the TextFields to enter the data corresponding to a particular item.

Once you confirm the entry, send a request to a Firebase database to store these values.

Now, in your real app, you can use a Firebase extension to request data from this server and populate it in your app as required.